# Как сделать кнопку, которая будет перекидывать на определённый сайт

Tags: html, css, button

Вот есть код кнопки на html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html> 
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="Lite"> 
   <center> 
    <h1>Official LiteBot</h1> 
   </center>
   <center>
   <button type="button" name="run_script">Добавить бота</button> 
   </center>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Вот стилизация на css

```css
button[name="run_script"] { 
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: #ff9900;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }
  button[name="run_script"]:hover { 
    background: #ff6600;
  }
```

И я хочу сделать так, чтобы после того как я нажимал на эту кнопку:
[image]
Меня перекидывало на определённый сайт
**Помогите пожалуйста!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="Lite"> 
   <center> 
    <h1>Official LiteBot</h1> 
   </center>
   <center>
      <a href="https://google.com" class="button">google</a>
   </center>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```